# How can I open DVD drive by making Windows API calls in Java?

Tags: java, windows, winapi, java-native-interface, jna

How can i use Windows API functions in Java?
I'm searching for a reference to guide me about using the Windows API in my Java application on Windows.

For example, I want to control a DVD drive in my Java application. How would I go about doing that?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using either JNA (Java Native Access) or JNI (Java Native Interface).

With [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) you can use `com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32` to call `DeviceIoControl`, which will allow you to control your DVD drive.

Comment: So which commands and codes shoud I use?

Comment: After adding JNA as a dependency library, you should call `Kernel32.DeviceIoControl` to control the DVD drive (open or close). Perhaps another answer will also include a snippet, I'm a little too busy for that kind of investment right now :)